# Sql joins Displaying only available times

Tags: sql, join, rdbms

What I'm trying to do is the following:-

Query my database to show only the time-slots which haven't been used and populate it to a drop down box. (I know how to populate it to the drop down box.)

This is what I have:-
(Tables)

```
     Appointment:-             Availability:-
     AppointmentTime           AvailabilityTime
     AppointmentDate           EmployeeId
     ClientID
     EmployeeId
```

From researching around I'm pretty certain I need to have a join command in my SQL statement.

To me the logical way of doing this is that in order to achieve what I want I need to check the AvailabilityTime and employee ID against that in the appointments table and if there isn't a match that should mean that chosen appointment time is free so this gives grounds to display all available free slots.

The problem is I am not quite sure how to go about doing this SQL wise, any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you post some sample data and desired o/p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your schema is messed up (you have time in one table, and date & time in another). But the gist would be something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM Availability
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1
    FROM Appointment
    WHERE Appointment.AppointmentTime = Availability.AvailabilityTime
        AND Appointment.EmployeeID = Availability.EmployeeID
)
```